# Ошибка при сборке проекта Unity3D под Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Добрый день. Подскажите при сборке проекта выбивает ошибку

```
\\?\C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Picters\Temp\gradleOut\AN_Res\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\release\AndroidManifest.xml:23:24-40: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
```

Но в самом манифесте `@string/app_name` прописано. Как быть?

Полный Log `https://pastebin.com/yP2evebX`

Answer (score 1):

Все спасибо, использовал `Asset` для `Unity`, что бы иметь доступ к компонентам android, но Unity не хотел собирать приложение через `Gradle`. После обращения к разработчикам `asseta`, все заработало. Пришлось немного исправить манифест. Вот их ответ.

Вам необходимо будет открыть AndroidManifest из папки `Plugins/Android/AN_Res.` Удалите `android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name"` из тега `<application>`.